# How to compile Maven project effectively and fast

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with 13 sub modules. I have two questions how to optimize the build process:

1. I want to compile the Java code only for x86-64 server. How I con configure Maven to do this?
2. I have a server with 4 CPU cores. Is it possible to use multi-threading for compiling the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. I want to compile the Java code only for x86-64 server. How I con configure Maven to do this?

Java is cross platform. You can't make it compile for only x86-64.

> .2. I have a server with 4 CPU cores. Is it possible to use multi-threading for compiling the code?

The `javac` is multi-threaded. It might not use all the cores you have, but that's as multi-threaded as you can make it.

As Andrew notes, you can make the build multi-threaded which causes the tests to be run concurrently (something which might break your tests)  This doesn't make the compilation concurrent.

Comment: not completely corretn - you can put your x86-64-specific build under a maven profile which is only active under x86-64. see http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html

Comment: @radai You're right but, anyway, the bytecode produced will be executable for every OS / Arch, so there is no specific configuration to build bytecode *Only for* x86-64. There is just a way to build *when you compile on* x86-64

Comment: true. i understood the question to mean the OP has part of the build that's only relevant on x86-64 machines

Comment: Youve gave all the information I was searching for hours :)

Answer (score 15):

2) `mvn package -T 2C` will build with 2 Threads per CPU core

Comment: by default you don't have to change anything in pom.xml. Be aware that you MIGHT run into issues with non-threadsafe maven plugins. If there are new (i.e. thread-safe) version of these plugins I would try to update the pluginversion in the poms

Answer (score 5):

1. Maven invokes standard `javac`.
2. Yes, it is possible, see [Parallel builds in Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago I [read](https://gist.github.com/2508909) about this pom configuration to improve compiler performance

```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           .....
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                   <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.6</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </plugin>
```

I did not try it but it may be interesting for you.

The explanation of this improvement can be found [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-202).

Comment: now THAT's interesting to know. do you happen to know if this becomes the default in some newer version of the compiler plugin ?

Comment: @radai As I just checked the current version of the maven-compiler-plugin 2.5.1 already depends on plexus-compiler-javac:1.9.1 (see [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom)) - so this answer ist only interesting if you are running older maven versions.

Comment: For me it improved the build speed.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to parallel builds (-Tn flag mentioned above) see if you can hide away all sorts of extra stuff under profiles - configure tests to be off by default, do all sorts of tagging, code analysis, distribution to remote repositories etc optionally.
you could also try throwing more memory at maven (MAVEN_OPTS env. var)